# my if statement is never happening true in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

if staemnt never happening true. so please help me. i tried changing some stuff and hope it will work but it never did and only else staement is working.

```
package com.example.managemntsystem

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var input = editText.text
        var empList = arrayListOf<String>("jacob", "raf", "boss", "john")


        button.setOnClickListener {

            if (input == emplist) {

                textView2.setText("WORKING")

            }else{

                textView2.setText("Not working")

            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: That's because you're comparing a `String` to an `ArrayList<String>` which will never evaluate to `true`.

Comment: What do you want to compare in your code?

Answer (score 4):

use this instead:

```
if (empList.contains(input.toString()))
```

This will check if the content of the EditText is equal to any of the list items. Remember to call `toString()` method when you want the EditText content.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [in](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#inOperation) operator:

```
if (input in empList)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empList.contains(input))
```

I think this will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your `var input = editText.text` never gets set again (even though it is a `var`), so in this case, It's not different from a val. You either need to reassign it or use `.text` directly:

1. Set it again:

var input = editText.text
var empList = arrayListOf("jacob", "raf", "boss", "john")

```
button.setOnClickListener {

input = editText.text // add this line

f (input == emplist) {

        textView2.setText("WORKING")

    }else{

        textView2.setText("Not working")

    }
}
```

2. Or not use input at all and use text itself:

   ```
   button.setOnClickListener {

   if (editText.text == emplist) {

       textView2.setText("WORKING")

   }else{

       textView2.setText("Not working")

           }
   }
   ```